# GroupIDs in Azure Data Factory and create dynamically columns

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a table with three columns:

```
name, amount, charge (e.g. Apple, 5, XX)
```

Unfortunately I have multiple rows with the same ID. But different amounts and different charges.
I want to merge those informations into one final column. like

```
name, amountXX, amountYY
```

So technically speaking:
When ID found and Charge == XX, then group by ID, and insert amount of that ID in amountXX.
When ID found and charge == YY, then group by ID, and insert amount of that ID in amountYY.

Final example:

123, 20, chargeXX
123, 15, chargeYY
345, 10, chargeXX
345, 40, chargeYY

The final aggregate output would be:

name, chargeXX, chargeYY
123, 20, 15
345, 10, 40

I used the window aggreate flowlet and aggregated first by ID to group them. But wasn't able to insert the charge numbers correctly.
Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to pivot your data based on the "charge" column. You can achieve this using the Pivot transformation in Azure Data Factory Mapping Data Flows instead of aggregate transformation. Below is the approach.

1. Add a Source transformation to your data flow and select your table as the source.

**Sample input:**

```
name,amount,charge
Apple,5,XX
Apple,7,XX
Apple,5,YY
Apple,6,ZZ
Orange,9,ZZ
Orange,7,YY
Orange,8,XX
```

2. Add a Pivot transformation to your data flow.
3. In the Pivot transformation, select the "name" column as the Group By column.
   [image]
4. Select the "charge" column as the Pivot Key column.
   [image]
5. In the Pivoted Columns section, give sum(amount) as pivot expression.
6. In the Column Name Pattern section, enter "charge" as prefix value.
   [image]

**Output of pivot data**
[image]